# CURL in current domain return 127.0.0.1

Tags: php, ubuntu

I have this PHP code that get the IP Address from a website using CURL:

```
$ip = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_PRIMARY_IP);
```

When I put another site different from mine, it returns the ip correctly, but from the moment I inform my domain it returns `127.0.0.1`

How can I solve this? Is it on the server itself?

Comment: Are you developing this locally through a VM or something like XAMPP/WAMPP?

Comment: @AdamA, No I'm developing this code in my webserver (Digital Ocean) That I install apache and php.

Comment: What's the output when you run the following: $ip = gethostbyname('www.yourdomain.com');

echo $ip;